# ECONNREFUSED MongoDB running in kubernetes cluster

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I'm a beginner to docker and kubernetes. I have docker containers running inside pods on the kubernetes cluster and I'm trying to connect to mongo db but it keeps failing

when I check my pods and services, everything is running all good:

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE

auth-depl-65565b6884-rxcvj         1/1     Running   0          58s

auth-mongo-depl-6c87496969-9sxj4   1/1     Running   0          56s


NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE

auth-mongo-srv   ClusterIP   10.106.91.10    <none>        27017/TCP   2m

auth-srv         ClusterIP   10.96.108.116   <none>        3000/TCP    2m3s

kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP     2m20s
```

My Mongo Deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-depl
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-depl
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-depl
          image: mongo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-srv
spec:
  selector:
    type: ClusterIP
    app: mongo-depl
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

Connection to DB:

```
const start = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://auth-mongo-srv:27017/auth", {
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    console.log("connected to db");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

When I check my logs, I get this error:

```
[auth] MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.106.91.10:27017
 reason: TopologyDescription {                                            
   type: 'Single',                                                        
   setName: null,                                                         
   maxSetVersion: null,                                                   
   maxElectionId: null,                                                   
   servers: Map(1) { 'auth-mongo-srv:27017' => [ServerDescription] },     
   stale: false,                                                          
   compatible: true,                                                      
   compatibilityError: null,                                              
   logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,                                    
   heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,                                           
   localThresholdMS: 15,                                                  
   commonWireVersion: null                                                
 }
```

Any clues what may cause the problem?

Comment: are you running this on local machine using Docker desktop on MacOS?

Comment: I'm running it locally but on windows with Docker desktop

Comment: Side note : `type: ClusterIP` should be under `spec` and not `selector` I guess.

Comment: @michalk ooh, thanks I now see my mistake

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have missconfigured the selector for the service. You have added a label `type: ClusterIP` so your mongo pods are not picked by this service because they do not have such label. You probably wanted to add `type: ClusterIP` under the `spec`, not `selector`. So remove label `type: ClusterIP` from the selector and optionally put it under `spec` (`ClusterIP` type is the default for the service).

Answer (score 0):

You must configure a port on your pod's container such as:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-depl
          image: mongo
          ports:
          - containerPort: 27017
```

See [Connecting Applications with Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/)
, stating

> Create [a] Pod, and **note that it has a container port specification**

Answer (score 0):

> thanks I now see my mistake – Kevin M plug Sep 15 at 11:06

That's because of the Kubernetes (k8s) service is just "an abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service" [(link)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

That "set of Pods" is the `Endpoint`. you can check `Endpoints` with the `kubectl get ep` command. That is why the very first step is to check if there are endpoints for the `auth-mongo-srv` service.

The Service spec you have created results in:

```
$ kubectl get svc auth-mongo-srv -o wide 
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE   SELECTOR
auth-mongo-srv   ClusterIP   10.0.9.213   <none>        27017/TCP   30s   app=mongo-depl,type=ClusterIP

$ kubectl get ep auth-mongo-srv 
NAME             ENDPOINTS   AGE
auth-mongo-srv   <none>      8m47s
```

As you can see, no endpoint for that service is created, because k8s couldn't match the Service selector with any `Pod` that lists the same set of selectors.

In this case it is needed to adjust `auth-mongo-srv`.

Sometimes you might want to create `Endpoint`'s manually ( ["Headless Services"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) and [services without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)).